# Why does the mean velocity of gas particles include $\pi$?

Tags: pi, chemistry

In chemistry, we are learning about kinetic molecular theory (KMT) of gasses, and I just couldn't help being surprised when I saw pi in the equation of mean velocity. I know that whenever $\pi$ is involved in an equation, it somehow involves circles, but KMT assumes that the molecules are points. I don't know how to add equations here from mobile, but here it is: $\sqrt{\frac{8RT}{\pi M}}$, where $R$ is the universal gas constant (8.3144 J/K mol), T stands for the temperature in Kelvin, and M is the molar mass of the molecule.

It just fascinates me that $\pi$ is everywhere, especially here and I would like to know why.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll probably have better luck in physics stack exchange with this question.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinetic-theory-of-gases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When studying the KMT, you should be familiar with these equations:

1) Number of microstates:
$$W=\frac{N!}{\prod_{i}n_{i}!}$$
2) Gibbs entropy:
$$S=-k\sum_{i}p_{i}\ln p_{i}$$
3) Boltzmann distribution:
$$p_{i}=Ke^{-\frac{E_{i}}{kT}},$$
which implies the Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution:
$$f(v)=4\pi \left(\frac{m}{2\pi kT}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}v^2 e^{-\frac{mv^2}{2kT}}$$

Now the mean velocity is calculated by $\langle v\rangle =\int_0^\infty vf(v)\, \mathrm dv,$ so
$$\langle v\rangle =4\pi \left(\frac{m}{2\pi kT}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\int_0^\infty v^3e^{-\frac{mv^2}{2kT}}\, \mathrm dv,$$
which evaluates to $\sqrt{\frac{8kT}{\pi m}}=\sqrt{\frac{8RT}{\pi M}}$.

To sum it up, $\pi$ comes from the fact that
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-v^2}\, \mathrm dv =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$